# Why is it necessary to wrap our contour around the branch cut at $+ im$ in the spacelike Klein-Gordon propagator? (P&S)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, complex-numbers, propagator, klein-gordon-equation

This question is in reference to eq. (2.52) on the bottom of page 27 in Peskin and Schroeder.

To evaluate the Klein-Gordon field propagator along a spacelike interval we wrap the contour around the branch cut at $p=+im$. My question is (possibly a mathematical one) why it is necessary to move the contour in the first place? The function is analytic along the real axis, which is what we are originally integrating along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Peskin and Schroeder want to show is that the integral is non-zero. You could certainly try to exactly compute the integral over the original contour. However, I imagine that it's probably a lot easier to use the new contour wrapped around $p=im$. In any case, along the new contour, it is immediately clear that the integral is non-zero because the integrand is always positive. This is not clear along the original contour.

Comment: Ah I see, it is just more instructive to use that contour. Thank you :)

Comment: Doesn't the P&S contour have a flaw?  The end points of the distorted contour need to stay at their original positions (opposite ends of the real line)  and so P&S neglect to show that the large quarter circle arc integrals at infinity linking those end points to the top of the branch cut (also at infinity) are zero?  I ask, because it's not at all obvious to me why they would be zero. Jordan's lemma, for example, is not sufficient to show they go to zero. Jordans lemma only tells me that the sum of the integrals on the two arcs is less than pi/r (not pi/R, with R being. rhe 'radius' of p).

Comment: I have found some discussion of the point I have just made here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/557390/362800 though it is a bit short on detail so I am not (yet) convinced by the explanation given there -- but I do agree that the author of that post is correct to attempt to answer it.

Comment: In attempt to get a discussion going on the point I've raised in my last two comments, I have created a more detailed/explicit question of my own on the topic here:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/758661/what-is-the-missing-part-of-the-argument-needed-to-justify-the-claim-of-2-52-i